# tcpdump is showing "Ignored Unknown Record"

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump

I am not able to understand the TLS Version from the tcpdump captured multiple times, between my tool and MSSQL 2014 DB.

All its showing me is,

Frame 917: 121 bytes on wire (968 bits), 121 bytes captured (968 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Vmware_a3:5e:5c (00:50:56:a3:5e:5c), Dst: All-HSRP-routers_01 (00:00:0c:07:ac:01)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 9.109.114.88, Dst: 9.109.117.146
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 53383, Dst Port: 1433, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 67
**Secure Sockets Layer
    Ignored Unknown Record
        [Expert Info (Warning/Protocol): Ignored Unknown Record]**
            [Ignored Unknown Record]
            [Severity level: Warning]
            [Group: Protocol]

Comment: how do I attach the tcpdump file?